# Insert quantity of each types of item on same row

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have problem in making the quantity of each item to appear on same row.The student with matric number 1234 should have his big bag quantity to be 2 and the small bag quantity should be 3. While student number 65527 should have 3 big bag but 0 small bag. 
Below is how my table appear before I use `GROUP_CONCAT` command:

[image]

The year does not appear at the year column but at small bag column and the quantity appear on different row.

Below is what it look like when I tried on `GROUP_CONCAT` command:
[image]

The year still does not appear at the year column and the quantity of each bag appear on same column.

This is what my mysql `GROUP_CONCAT` command look like:

```
$sql_join = "SELECT s.student_id,s.student_name,s.student_contact,s.student_status,s.student_room, i.invstu_year, i.invstu_sem, l.location_house, GROUP_CONCAT(b.baggage_type) as 'Products', GROUP_CONCAT(i.invbag_quantity) as 'Quantity', GROUP_CONCAT(b.price) as 'Price' FROM inventory i JOIN student s on i.invstu_id = s.student_id JOIN baggage b on b.baggage_id = i.invbag_id JOIN location l on l.location_id = i.invloc_id GROUP BY i.invstu_id";
$result_join =  mysqli_query($connect,$sql_join);
```

This is how I specify the command for table:

```
<?php
    $counter = 1;
    while($row_join= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_join))
    { ?>
     <tr>
     <td><?php echo $counter; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_join["student_name"]; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_join["student_id"]; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_join["Quantity"]; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_join["invstu_year"]; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_join["invstu_sem"]; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_join["location_house"]; ?></td>
     </tr>
    <?php   
        $counter++;
    }
    ?>
```

I try to look for other example but couldn't find it. I may miss out some example and would really appreciate it if there is any suggested example which I could refer to.

Comment: where is your `table header` part..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT will group both the values together in to the same string, you could use PHP Explode to split the string if the values will always be in the same place.

Something like

```
$Bags = explode(",", $row_join["Quantity"]);
```

and

```
<td><?php echo $Bags[0]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $Bags[1]; ?></td>
```

To clarify, it is grouping the values as "2,3" currently, explode as a function will split the string in to an array, $Bags becomes [2,3], so you would use $Bags[0] to access the first number, $Bags[1] to access the second.

Comment: Thanks the code you suggested work. But now the problem is at the second student. Since the second student only have big bag and does not have small bag, it generate an error. This is the error: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 . I'll try to modify my code to set the unselected bag types to 0. Thanks once again. :)

Comment: I see, alternatively, you could use a second SQL statement if there would only be two choices for bags, but it would get a bit crazy if you had more options.

Comment: Haha. Unfortunately I do have more than 2 options. As the system are supposed to be able to add more baggage types....

Comment: and im guessing, based of the results so far, you have one record per baggage type. So if they dont have small bags, there will not be an entry saying they have 0 small bags?

Comment: how about something like: "GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{type:"', i.invbag_quantity'", qty:"',b.baggage_type,'"}')) bags"
which would give you a value of "small:2, big:3", and then using php to parse the data?